# Error 41 - Required SSSE3 instruction set not supported by the cpu

Tags: camera, raspbian-stretch, driver

I'm trying to connect the [ueye](https://en.ids-imaging.com/home.html) camera to a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ over usb.

I downloaded the [Linux drivers](http://www.ids-imaging.com/go/edmund/) and tried to install it.

However, upon installation I got this error:

> Error 41 - Required SSSE3 instruction set not supported by the cpu

I tried finding a way to update the gcc compiler after some googling but didn't work.

Is there any way I can install the drivers an get this to work anyways or should I just don't bother?

Comment: what research about the SSSE3 instruction set have you done?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3#CPUs_with_SSSE3

Comment: obviously not enough, which is kinda of why I'm here. So I guess, there's not way I can get this to work

Comment: it appears that SSSE3 is an Intel extension and is supported by some of the Intel processors ... not sure about AMD .... nothing else supports it ... there may be a software emulation library for the Arm processor